# Regex Conditions C#

Tags: c#, regex

how to keep condition that if condition is false then whole regex is not matched
to particular text

for example if `\s{1,37}` is false than nothing is matched

**Edit:-1**

I want help in following case

I want to put a condition that if there are not 37 space available in text then regex match must terminate

**Edit-2**

```
 25                        8765.00        219125.00                 0.55                  -219125.00
```

consider this if there are not exact 37 space after 25 then further match shoul be close

Comment: Please clarify your question, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Please add more details. Your question is very vague at the moment.

Comment: Care to enlighten us about the rest of your Regex pattern?

Comment: it just matches numbers

Comment: Numbers *and* 37 spaces? What is the format of your input that you want to pass/fail? Give us some sample data to work with.

Comment: Doesn't a mere `\s{37}` work? It will require exactly 37 whitespaces and won't match if there are fewer whitespaces.

Comment: I think now that you need to make sure there is a non-whitespace char before 37 whitespaces: `(?<!\s)\s{37}\d+`. This will only match 37 (exactly) whitespaces and 1+ digits. No need for additional code as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to short-circuit the Regex engine that way. You can use the control verbs `(*FAIL)` to immediately fail a match or `(*LIMIT_MATCH=x)` to limit the number of matches you receive to a specific quantity, but I don't believe there's a way to dynamically tell the engine to just stop matching entirely on reaching a specific condition.

***(Note: According to Wiktor Stribizew in the comments, .NET's Regex engine does not actually support control verbs, so consider the previous paragraph an exercise in general theory.)***

What you can do instead is to get all the matches of numbers preceded by spaces like so:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @" +[\d.-]+");
```

Then loop through them to see if the number of leading spaces is exactly 37:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    if (match.Value.Count(c => c == ' ') != 37)
        break;

    // continue processing
}
```

Comment: thanks sir worked like charm

Comment: The first paragraph is entirely wrong as .NET regex does not support PCRE control verbs (and thus there is no point mentioning them here), and there is a way to just stop matching on a specific condition - with lookarounds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew To the first point, I did not know that and it's good information to know. To the second point, lookarounds can stop the matching on a particular potential match, not on the entire process as a whole (as in later substrings that would otherwise match would instead get ignored).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unless of course I"m wrong about that as well. If so, by all means, add another answer and show me how to do it.

Comment: I cannot add an answer because the question is too vague.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The new information in the edit makes the question pretty straight forward: A Regex (or in my case, alternative solution) that would match an input of numbers separated by spaces but would abort matching if the space count before the numbers is not exactly 37.